# Why are my jQuery hide events not firing and my Backbone sub view not rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

Now Solved - See bottom....

I've got a Backbone list view with a button on it that should show the edit elements.

Neither the jQuery hide() call in the 'showAddEntry' function or the view rendering for 'versionEditView' are doing anything at all. I've stepped right through and I'm not getting any errors. I've even tried manually running methods in the console to see what's going on with hide, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Here's the main view...

```
define(['ministry', 'jquery', 'models/m-version-info', 'views/about/v-edit-version-info-entry', 'text!templates/version-info/version-info.html'],
function(Ministry, $, VersionInfo, VersionInfoEditView, TemplateSource) {
    var versionInfoEntriesView = Ministry.View.extend({

        el: '#mainAppArea',

        template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

        versionInfoEditView: null,

        initialize: function () {
            this.$addEntryArea = $('#addVersionInfoEntryArea');
            this.$addEntryButton = $('#addVersionInfoEntryButton');
        },

        events: {
            'click #addVersionInfoEntryButton': 'showAddEntry'
        },

        render: function () {
            var that = this;
            var entries = new VersionInfo.Collection();

            entries.fetch({
                success: function (data) {
                    that.$el.html(that.template({ items: data.toJSON() }));
                }
            });

            return this;
        },

        showAddEntry: function() {
            if (this.versionInfoEditView != null) {
                this.versionInfoEditView.trash();
            }

            this.versionInfoEditView = new VersionInfoEditView({ el: this.$addEntryArea });
            this.$addEntryButton.hide();
            this.versionInfoEditView.render();
            return false;
        }
    });

    return versionInfoEntriesView;
});
```

And here's the child view...

```
define(['ministry', 'models/m-version-info', 'text!templates/version-info/edit-version-info-  entry.html', 'jquery.custom'],
function (Ministry, VersionInfo, TemplateSource) {

    var editVersionInfoView = Ministry.View.extend({

        template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

        initialize: function () {
            this.$dbVersionInput = this.$('#dbVersion');
            this.$tagInput = this.$('#tag');
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'submit .edit-version-info-form': 'saveEntry'
        },

        saveEntry: function() {
            var entry = new VersionInfo.Model({ dbVersion: this.$dbVersionInput.val(), tag: this.$tagInput.val() });
            entry.save({
                success: function() {
                    alert('Your item has been saved');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    return editVersionInfoView;
});
```

And the main template...

```
<h2>Version Info</h2>
<div id="info">
    <a id="addVersionInfoEntryButton" href="#/versioninfo">Add manual entry</a>
    <div id="addVersionInfoEntryArea">
    </div>
    <ul id="items">
        {{#each items}}
        <li>{{dbVersion}} | {{tag}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the edit template...

```
<form class="edit-version-info-form">
    <h3>Create a new entry</h3>
    <label for="dbVersion">DB Version</label>
    <input type="text" id="dbVersion" maxlength="10" />
    <label for="tag">Tag</label>
    <input type="text" id="tag" />
    <button type="submit" id="newEntryButton">Create</button>
</form>
```

I'm fairly new to backbone so I may well be doing something totally wrong, but I can't see anything wrong with the approach so far and it's not throwing any errors.

OK - Fix as follows after some facepalming...

```
define(['ministry', 'jquery', 'models/m-version-info', 'views/about/v-edit-version-info-entry', 'text!templates/version-info/version-info.html'],
function(Ministry, $, VersionInfo, VersionInfoEditView, TemplateSource) {
    var versionInfoEntriesView = Ministry.View.extend({

        el: '#mainAppArea',

        template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

        versionInfoEditView: null,

        $addEntryArea: undefined, 
        $addEntryButton: undefined,

        initialize: function () {
        },

        events: {
            'click #addVersionInfoEntryButton': 'showAddEntry'
        },

        render: function () {
            var that = this;
            var entries = new VersionInfo.Collection();

            entries.fetch({
                success: function (data) {
                    that.$el.html(that.template({ items: data.toJSON() }));
                    that.$addEntryArea = that.$('#addVersionInfoEntryArea');
                    that.$addEntryButton = that.$('#addVersionInfoEntryButton');
                }
            });

            return this;
        },

        showAddEntry: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.versionInfoEditView != null) {
                this.versionInfoEditView.trash();
            }

            this.versionInfoEditView = new VersionInfoEditView({ el: this.$addEntryArea });
            this.$addEntryButton.hide();
            this.$addEntryArea.append('Do I want to put it here?');
            this.versionInfoEditView.render();
        }
    });

    return versionInfoEntriesView;
});
```

The issue was due to the fact that I was setting the internal element variables within the view before the completion of the render, so the elements were linked up to nothing. I resolved this by extracting the element initiation to the end of the render success callback.

Comment: I found a fix for this.

Comment: Could you post the fix so everyone came to this question afterwards can find the solution. Note that you also can accept your own answer as the solution.

Comment: It's all time limited - I answered it within an hour so I couldn't post it as an answer, which is a bit crazy. This fix is posted up at the end of the question.

Comment: Answer now added properly (been promoted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix again...

```
define(['ministry', 'jquery', 'models/m-version-info', 'views/about/v-edit-version-info-entry',     'text!templates/version-info/version-info.html'],
function(Ministry, $, VersionInfo, VersionInfoEditView, TemplateSource) {
var versionInfoEntriesView = Ministry.View.extend({

    el: '#mainAppArea',

    template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateSource),

    versionInfoEditView: null,

    $addEntryArea: undefined, 
    $addEntryButton: undefined,

    initialize: function () {
    },

    events: {
        'click #addVersionInfoEntryButton': 'showAddEntry'
    },

    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var entries = new VersionInfo.Collection();

        entries.fetch({
            success: function (data) {
                that.$el.html(that.template({ items: data.toJSON() }));
                that.$addEntryArea = that.$('#addVersionInfoEntryArea');
                that.$addEntryButton = that.$('#addVersionInfoEntryButton');
            }
        });

        return this;
    },

    showAddEntry: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.versionInfoEditView != null) {
            this.versionInfoEditView.trash();
        }

        this.versionInfoEditView = new VersionInfoEditView({ el: this.$addEntryArea });
        this.$addEntryButton.hide();
        this.$addEntryArea.append('Do I want to put it here?');
        this.versionInfoEditView.render();
    }
});

return versionInfoEntriesView;
});
```

The issue was due to the fact that I was setting the internal element variables within the view before the completion of the render, so the elements were linked up to nothing. I resolved this by extracting the element initiation to the end of the render success callback.